# Compatibility issue when Surface Pro 3 with Windows 10 connects to iOS 15 Wi-Fi Hotspot

Tags: wireless-networking, iphone

After upgrading my iPhone to iOS 15, my Surface Pro 3 with Windows 10 can no longer connect to the Wi-Fi hotspot on the iPhone. It shows an error message "Can't connect to this network". This error doesn't go away with retrying. Resetting the network settings on iPhone doesn't help.

Answer (score -1):

After some search and trying, I found the following information from a [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/q7g6gc/surface_pro_3_and_ios15_hotspot_connection_issues/) helps:

> jackdog165
>
> Thanks for the hint of the WPA3. I was able to fix our Surface Pro 3's to work with iOS15 iPhones and iPads.
>
> I downloaded the driver from (2nd one listed):
> https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=15.68.17015.112
>
> Extracted it to a folder then updated the driver through device manager.

Comment: this answer is very old. the thread there talks about that version being worked into regular windows update. my regular windows update have a newer version today already, and it still cannot use wpa3. so i doubt that was the fix then either.